# Does anybody have any feedback on SeeBeyond / Sun's JCAPS product

Tags: java, soa, esb

I have a client currently thinking about using SeeBeyond / Sun's [JCAPS](http://www.sun.com/software/javaenterprisesystem/javacaps/index.jsp) product, does anyone on SO have any positive or negative experiences using / developing for it ?

Answer (score 3):

SeeBeyond/JCAPS might not have a future now that Oracle has bought Sun.

Answer (score 1):

JCAPS 6 is quite convenient for Integration problematic (hospital in my case); however the design pattern used here (Message routing) might be a bit complicated to set up from scratch.

JCAPS 6 is also far better, easier, faster ... than it's ancestor eGate:)

Answer (score 1):

I done JCAPS for a while now, If you try using JDeveloper it may be harder since you need to set up a lot of other stuff rather than just code for your needs. For example like ant build and also apache web service.

If you focus on developing a fast integration, JCAPS would be better. But then again, you still need to do some performance tuning before it is really good. Not so sure about TIBCO since they are well known also.

Answer (score 0):

maybe rather look into using JDeveloper. Its user interface is very similar to jcaps, and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as developing SOA solutions go, Java CAPS is very useful.
However, Oracle's plan for this product is not that clear. They said they would not have any new feature releases; instead, they will have only maintenance releases. They are focusing on Weblogic SOA product suit.